# Add common prefix to all cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column with some text in each cell.
I want to add some text, for example "X", at the start of all cells. For example:

```
A             B
-----  >>>>  ----
1            X1
2            X2
3            X3
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Type this in cell B1, and copy down...

```
="X"&A1
```

This would also work:

```
=CONCATENATE("X",A1)
```

And here's one of many ways to do this in VBA (Disclaimer: I don't code in VBA very often!):

```
Sub AddX()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        .Cells(i, 2).Value = "X" & Trim(Str(.Cells(i, 1).Value))
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Adam- Is there any way to do it without copy,paste?  
I mean in the same column.

Comment: @LIX:  sure.  You can use the VBA code I have provided.  In general, I find that using Excel formulae will only get you so far.  For anything beyond the trivial, you'll need something more powerful anyway, so it may not hurt to start learning VBA now.  Best of luck.

Comment: how do you copy down a formula?

Comment: @JohnB: left-click and drag downwards the small black box at the lower-right corner of the cell.

Comment: CONCATENATE doesn't work for me, my cell value is (e.g.) 14:30:00, which is crappy output by Excel.

Comment: See @Shajith.m's and Shawon's  answers below - the custom number format "X"@ is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 20):

Select the cell you want to be like this,
Go To Cell Properties (or CTRL 1)
under Number tab
in custom
enter
"X"#

Comment: Could you make an example? For me, the custom format (already) is "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM", totally not sure where Excel gets this. What I want is to remove the last ":ss" (which are all zero and wrong) and put a "00:" in the front instead (as the hours/hh:).

Answer (score 19):

Select the cell you want to be like this, go to cell properties (or CTRL 1) under Number tab in custom enter "X"@

Put a space between " and @ if needed

Comment: I like this answer best.  Even though OPs example made it appear as though he wanted both columns, I don't think that was a requirement.  This is the only answer that avoids duplicate columns and I love it.

Answer (score 7):

Select the cell you want,

Go To Format Cells (or CTRL+1),

Select the "custom" Tab, enter your required format like : **"X"#**

use a space if needed.

for example, I needed to insert the word "Hours" beside my numbers and used this format : **# "hours"**

Answer (score 3):

1. Enter the function of `= CONCATENATE("X",A1)`  in one cell other than A say D
2. Click the Cell D1, and drag the fill handle  across the range that you want to fill.All the cells should have been added the specific prefix text.

You can see the changes made to the repective cells.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
select the cell(s), under formatting/number/custom formatting, type in

"BOB" General

now  you have a prefix "BOB" next to numbers, dates, booleans, but not next to TEXTs

Option2: 
As before, but use the following format

_ "BOB" @_

now  you have a prefix BOB, this works even if the cell contained text

Cheers, Sudhi

Answer (score 0):

Michael.. if its just for formatting then you can format the cell to append any value.

Just right click and select Format Cell on the context menu, select custom and then specify type as you wish... for above example it would be X0. Here 'X' is the prefix and 0 is the numeric after.

Hope this helps..

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Format Cells - Custom. Type the required format into the list first. To prefix "0" before the text characters in an Excel column, use the Format 0####. Remember, use the character "#" equal to the maximum number of digits in a cell of that column. For e.g., if there are 4 cells in a column with the entries - 123, 333, 5665, 7 - use the formula 0####. Reason - A single # refers to reference of just one digit.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

1. Put your prefix in one column say column A in excel
2. Put the values to which you want to add prefix in another column say column B in excel
3. In Column C, use this formula;

"C1=A1&B1"

4. Copy all the values in column C and paste it again in the same selection but as values only.

Answer (score 0):

Type a value in one cell (EX:B4 CELL). For temporary use this formula in other cell (once done delete it). =CONCAT(XY,B4) . click and drag till the value you need. Copy the whole column and right click paste only values (second option).

I tried and it's working as expected.