# Is there a VBA code which allows modification of number while keeping the word constant within a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry the previous question I posted is not very detailed.
Is there any VBA code where I can change the number while keeping the word constant within a cell? Since I'm from Indonesia, and doing a monthly report regarding the amount of production being produced by the production line, the word for box is "dus", so I was searching for a solution where I input a number and the word "dus" will appear along with it within the same cell. I'd like it to appear as the following:

```
23 dus
44 dus
15 dus
12 dus
```

As can be seen within the example, the numbers changed, the word "dus" remains the same. I'm new to VBA, so I don't know what codes should i use in order for it to function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add common prefix to all cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703431/add-common-prefix-to-all-cells-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can set the `NumberFormat` property. This uses the same syntax as the 'Format Cells...' option from right-clicking a cell, but, as you are adding text, you need to use double quotes to indicate a single quote.

```
Range("A1:A12").NumberFormat = "#"" dus"""
```

which is entered as `#" dus"` in the 'Format Cells...' dialog box.

Comment: But when I tried it, there's no choice for me to pick from when I right click and click on format cells where I can input what you mentioned above...